# Распределение точек в квадрате

Tags: python, геометрия, теория-вероятностей

Нам даны координаты вершин некоторого квадрата(квадрат не обязательно имеет стороны, параллельные осям). Необходимо выдать случайную точку этого квадрата.
Я придумал следующий алгоритм:

1. Генерируем 4 случайных числа, каждое из которых больше нуля и которые в сумме дают 1.
2. Далее просто находим выпуклую комбинацию вершин квадрата.
   Проблемой является то, что точки распределяются очень неравномерно, около вершин точек почти нет, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы распределение было равномерным. Какой алгоритм можно использовать для решения задачи?

Comment: А почему бы не брать две случайные координаты, скажем, от 0 до 1 (лишь бы они не были скоррелированы), а потом просто преобразовывать в соответствующую точку квадрата?

Comment: Кстати, если случайные числа "в сумме дают 1", то это уже не совсем случайные числа :)

Comment: Два случайных числа a, b в диапазоне [0, 1]. Случайная точка тогда ab p00 + a(1-b)p01 + (1-a)b p10 + (1-a)(1-b) p11.

Comment: P0 + V01*a+V03*b, где V01 и V03 - вектора сторон к смежным с P0 вершинам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте два случайных числа `a`, `b` из отрезка `[0, 1]`. Постройте из них выпуклую комбинацию вершин квадрата с коэффициентами `(1-a)(1-b)`, `a(1-b)`, `ab`, `(1-a)b`.